# Conditional density equalling the marginal does not imply independence?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, independence

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, then $f_{X|Y}(x|y) = f_X(x)$. Is the converse false?

I think it's false because suppose you have a set of i.i.d. random variables, $\{X_i\}$, with common CDF $F$. Then the CDF given the minimum, $X_{(1)}$, is $F(x) - F(X_1)$ if $x \geq X_1$. If the $X_i$s have density, then $f_{X_1|X_{(1)}}(x) = f(x)$ because $F(X_1)$ is constant with respect to $x$. But $X_1$ and $X_{(1)}$ are not independent, right?

Comment: no, it's not false. the converse is also true

Comment: Let $\mu(x,dy)$ be a regular conditional distribution for $Y$ given $X$. If $\mu(x,dy) = \mathcal L_Y(dy)$ for all $x$ then $$P(X\in B_1,Y\in B_2) = \int_{B_1}\int_{B_2}\mu(x,dy)\mathcal L_X(dx) = \int_{B_1}\int_{B_2}\mathcal L_Y(dy)\mathcal L_X(dx) = P(X\in B_1)P(X\in B_2)$$